# Sidekiq & Capistrano with mutiple workers on single queues

Tags: ruby, capistrano, sidekiq

We've got sidekiq working on our app and it's working great however locally I have 4 sidekiq workers each set to a single queue using

```
sidekiq -r config.rb -c 20 -q websites
```

I have four queues so I start in terminal

```
sidekiq -r config.rb -c 20 -q websites
sidekiq -r config.rb -c 20 -q cafes
sidekiq -r config.rb -c 20 -q gyms
sidekiq -r config.rb -c 20 -q telephones
```

I've looked through the sidekiq documentation but I can't find the answer, I've added

```
set :sidekiq_processes, 4
```

which gives us four processes

and we've added priority to the queues as a short term solution.

I'd run the queues on the server manually but I don't want to lose the capistrano integration with starting and stopping with deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that with the built-in cap recipe.  You can process multiple queues and you can have multiple processes but you can't customize queues per process.

Comment: That's a shame (and I'd guess you'd know) What would you recommend?

Comment: I think the best thing might be to just make your own cap recipes for named queues, and then hook them into your deploy process. The easiest thing would be to have your own start/stop/restart methods and track what queues you want workers for in an array or something. See the built in recipes at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/capistrano.rb